# in Linux kernel module how can I read a file into this ? static const struct fw_data GSL1680_FW[] = {filecontent}

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, kernel-module

I attempting to modify an existing Linux Kernel module to load firmware
data from a file on the filesystem. I have examined many ways of doing 
this in other Module code all would require major modification to the existing
code. I would like to use a .h file to contain the modifications and retain
the driver file itself as is so that the modified driver can be more portable.

The way the driver is written it already calls a .h file to obtain the needed
values, however those are pre-set in the .h file what I would like to do is
have the .h file obtain the data from a configuration file on disk (flash as
this driver is for android) . I have searched extensively for a comparable
method of reading the data from a file but none store the data in the form needed by the module. Here is what is to hold the data :

```
struct fw_data
{
u32 offset : 8;
u32 : 0;
u32 val;
};

static const struct fw_data GSL1680_FW[] = {
{0xf0,0x3},
{0x00,0xa5a5ffc0},
{0x04,0x00000000},
{0x08,0xe810c4e1},
{0x0c,0xd3dd7f4d},
{0x10,0xd7c56634},
{0x14,0xe3505a2a},
{0x18,0x514d494f},
{0x1c,0xb83a7121},
{0x20,0x00000000},
{0x24,0x00000000},
{0x28,0x00000000},
{0x2c,0x00000000},
{0x30,0x00001000},
{0x34,0x00000000},
{0x38,0x00000000},
{0x3c,0x00000000},
{0x40,0x00000001},
{0x44,0x00000000},
{0x48,0x00000000},
{0x4c,0x00000000},
{0x50,0x00000000},
{0x54,0x01020304},
{0x58,0x05060708},
{0x5c,0x090a0b0c},
{0x60,0x0d0e0e0f},
{0x64,0x10111213},
{0x68,0x14151617},
{0x6c,0x18191a1b},
{0x70,0x1b1c1e1f},
{0x74,0x00000000},
{0x78,0x00010000},
{0x7c,0x8c846af3},
{0xf0,0x4},
{0x00,0x00000000},
{0x04,0x00000000},
{0x08,0x00000000},
{0x0c,0x00000000},
{0x10,0xffffff38},
{0x14,0x00000000},
{0x18,0x00000000},
{0x1c,0x00000000},
{0x20,0x00000000},
{0x24,0x00000000},
{0x28,0x00000000},
{0x2c,0x00000000},
{0x30,0x00002400},
{0x34,0x00000000},
{0x38,0x00000000},
{0x3c,0x00000000},
{0x40,0x00000000},
{0x44,0x00000002},
{0x48,0x00000001},
{0x4c,0x00004000},
{0x50,0x00000000},
{0x54,0x00010202},
{0x58,0x02030304},
{0x5c,0x05050606},
{0x60,0x07080909},
{0x64,0x0a0b0c0c},
{0x68,0x0d0e0f10},
{0x6c,0x11121416},
{0x70,0x16191c1e},
{0x74,0x00000000},
{0x78,0x80808080},
{0x7c,0x8c846af3},
{0xf0,0xb3},
{0x00,0x00001682},
{0x04,0x00000000},
{0x08,0x46656220},
{0x0c,0x20352032},
{0x10,0x30313300},
{0x14,0x00000000},
{0x18,0x31353a34},
{0x1c,0x383a3334},
{0x20,0x00000000},
{0x24,0x00000000},
{0x28,0x00000000},
{0x2c,0x00000000},
{0x30,0x00000000},
{0x34,0x00000000},
{0x38,0x00000000},
{0x3c,0x00000000},
{0x40,0x00000000},
{0x44,0x00000000},
{0x48,0x00000000},
{0x4c,0x00000000},
{0x50,0x00000000},
{0x54,0x00000000},
{0x58,0x00000000},
{0x5c,0x00000000},
{0x60,0x00000000},
{0x64,0x00000000},
{0x68,0x00000000},
{0x6c,0x00000000},
{0x70,0x00000000},
{0x74,0x00000000},
{0x78,0x00000000},
{0x7c,0x00000000},
};
```

I removed a large section of the included data as it is essentially the same differing only in addr, and data.. I think the above should give some Idea what is in there.

The values are a register location and the hex data for that location.

There are examples of Modules that I have found that load the data directly into the chip from the file accomplishing similar functionality, however those that I have found make some extensive changes to the Main module in order to accomplish this, and as I said I would like to retain the Main module as close to its existing form as possible so that the functionality can be implemented in differing versions of the module and more portable from one SOC model to the next with minimal modification to the Main Module between them.

I have tried to read the data into GSLX680[] using filp_read in several ways however I have not had much success.

I am far from an expert in C programming and have Never attempted to make this much of a modification to a module before, and have never had to deal with reading data from a file in kernel space before. I am simply a Hobbyist attempting to add functionality to a driver in order to have it solve many of the issues with differences in configuration on chinese made Android devices using the same SOC. Any help is Greatly appreciated.

Edit : I added the struct of fw_data above, I had not known it existed until reviewing all the code associated with this driver. This I am fairly sure at this point is the reason I could not get the data from the file into GSLX680[]. I am starting over now, any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks 
fsebentley

Comment: Can't you just flip_read(file, GSL1680_FW, sizeof(fw_data), 0) ? Or can you tell us what you tried and why it failed?

Comment: I have tried several different ways of doing the filp_read however I cannot

Comment: I goofed on that last one. I have attempted this using similar filp_read settings, my problem is that I cannot seem to initialize this static const struct fw_data GSL1680_FW[] = { File Contents } and have it use the data from the filp_read. it gives compile errors such as near initialization, GSL1680_FW size is not known, etc. I am fairly sure it is how I am attempting to put the data into this statement. I am unsure exactly the proper way to do that using the output of the file read. All examples of this I have place the data inside { } this does not work with the file read.

Comment: Ah now i got it. Assuming that first part of the structure is a byte and the other part is 4 bytes your struct would consist of one unsigned char and one usigned int. Also make sure your compiler does not add padding to that struct. You will have to pack it aligned to one byte. Then you need the file size divided by 6 lets call it x. Then you would init the struct with new new fw_data[x] and use the read function i posted above.

Comment: And sorry, divide it by 5 as its five bytes total not six sorry

Comment: This works in user space with a FILE fopen : fscanf(fwfile,"{%x,%x}, ",&offset,&val);   Now I need to find an equivalent read method that works with filp_open. I am looking at the f_op->read function but so far not able to read into the structure.